# How to compare values of two objects in C#

Tags: c#

I created a struct

```
 public struct MyCalender : IComparable<MyCalender>
{
 public int CompareTo(PersianDate other)
    {
        return DateTime.Compare(this, other);
    }
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
}
```

I new two object of this in a other UserControl, and i want compare they.

I use this code but i get error.

```
 MyCalender value = new MyCalender(2010,11,12);
 MyCalender value2 = new MyCalender(2010,11,12);
        if (value < value2) ==> geterror
```

Comment: Overload  the less than operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618500/needs-overload-operator-and-null-check

Comment: You've created a `struct`, not a `class`. There are big differences between the two, and you almost certainly should *not* be creating a `struct`.

Answer (score 5):

`IComparable` exposes [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx). `<` and `>` must be overloaded separately:

```
class Foo : IComparable<Foo>
{
    private static readonly Foo Min = new Foo(Int32.MinValue);

    private readonly int value;

    public Foo(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Foo other)
    {
        return this.value.CompareTo((other ?? Min).value);
    }

    public static bool operator <(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return (a ?? Min).CompareTo(b) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return (a ?? Min).CompareTo(b) > 0;
    }
}
```

I *edited* the code so that it does not fail when comparing against `null`. To keep it brief I used a shortcut that works unless `value` is `Int32.MinValue` for a proper `Foo`. Strictly speaking you'd have to check for `null` explicitly to get [the contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) right:

> By definition, any object compares greater than (or follows) null, and
>   two null references compare equal to each other.

Besides, implementing `IComparable<T>` means that `CompareTo(T value)` takes a parameter of `T`. Therefore `MyCalendar : IComparable<MyCalender>` should implement a method `CompareTo(MyCalendar other)` rather than `PersianDate` (or implement `IComparable<PersianDate>`).

Comment: thanks a lot, i use this code but when i use public Foo(int value)
i get error" must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller"

Comment: Did you initialize all `readonly` fields? The `Foo` class I wrote in VS2012 compiles, since `value` is initialized.

Comment: Yes it is readnly. I use vs2012 RC. I have 3 Initializes instance of the MyCalender structure.

Comment: Hang on, what did you do now? `Foo` is just an example class to show the principle. In `MyCalendar`, the operators need to get `MyCalendar` instances. Could you show us the code you've got now?

Comment: I added another paragraph about `MyCalendar` and `PersianDate`. I'm not sure whether `CompareTo` is implemented correctly in the first place. So, please show uf the full bit of relevant code :)

Answer (score 0):

if comparing just a datetime object,

would something like

```
  DateTime A = DateTime.Now, B = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
  var isqual = A.Date.CompareTo(B.Date);
```

do the trick?

or something like:

```
        class Calender
        {
            public DateTime datetime { get; set;}
        }

        class DateComparer : Calender, IComparable<Calender>
        {
            public int CompareTo(Calender other)
            {
                return other.datetime.Date.CompareTo(this.datetime.Date);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use CompareTo method that you already implemented instead of > in the line you posted or you need to overload > and < operators for your specific class. For instance:

```
public static bool operator >(MyCalendar c1, MyCalendar c2)
        {
            return c1.CompareTo(c2) > 0;
        }
        public static bool operator <(MyCalendar c1, MyCalendar c2)
        {
            return c1.CompareTo(c2) < 0;
        }
```

But keep in mind that you have to overload both of them.