# C# How to handle nullable types

Tags: c#, comparison

What's the proper way of dealing with nullable types like 'DateTime?'? When you need to pick a smaller of 2 dates that are nullable and one of them is null, < or > won't do as comparing null to actual date results in false, so for example:

```
DateTime? function( DateTime? a, DateTime? b ){
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

would return b if either a or b were null.

Do I have to use if-statements or is there a workaround?

**Edit:** I'd like not-null to be returned if one of the values is null

**Edit:** I'm sorry if it was confusing that I used a function as an example. It's not that I wanted to avoid using if-statements. But there's a lot of comparisms between nullable DateTimes and I'd like to avoid creating custom comparators that would require an explicti call and such.

Is it possible to override the default DateTime? comparators?

Comment: What the function must return if one of the parameters is null or both?

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: that depends entirely on what your application considers a null date to mean: are null dates smaller than all real dates? bigger than all real dates? is "null < DateTime.Now" even defined for your application?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I'd like the not-null value to be returned for either of comparisms ( greater than and less than )

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Nullable.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
static DateTime? GetLowerDateTime(DateTime? a, DateTime? b)
{
    int val = Nullable.Compare(a, b);
    if (val < 0) return a ?? b;
    if (val > 0) return b ?? a;
    return a; //whichever you want to return if they're equal
}
```

Comment: Or a little more compact: return Nullable.Compare(a, b) < 0? a: b;

Comment: @PiotrekDakanowski +1, nice.

Comment: @AlexD - You're right, I missed the addition about not returning a null. I've updated the answer. –

Comment: @keyboardP Great! Or, for the sake of readability, `return val < 0 ? a ?? b : val > 0 ? b ?? a : a != null ? a : null/*or whatever for null-null case*/` :-).

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime? function( DateTime? a, DateTime? b ){
    if(!a.HasValue && !b.HasValue)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    else if(!a.HasValue)
        return b;
    else if(!b.HasValue)
        return a;

    return a.Value < b.Value ? a : b;
}
```

Logic:

1. If both values are `null`, throw an exception.
2. If either A or B is `null`, return the other.
3. If neither A or B is `null`, return whichever is less than the other.

Comment: So there's no workaround and I gotta stick with if-statement?

Comment: The if statement is a way of making it explicit what you intend to happen once you have `null` DateTime's in the mix. Since you already know how you want your function to compare a null DateTime to a DateTime with a value, you *could* overload the operator like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618500/needs-overload-operator-and-null-check).

Comment: @Scorpion Thank you scorpio, I had no idea you could override comparators outside the class.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to compare `null` to `null`? They're equal. Comparing them is legal. Your function shouldn't throw.

Comment: @Scorpion I'm a bit stucked on overriding the operator outside the class as everywhere people say it's not possible.

Comment: @Lucas: You're perfectly able to compare `null` to `null`, but it's not clear whether the asker expects a `null` result from two `null` inputs. A throw seems a pretty reasonable exit if you're calling a function to pick the earlier date, but not passing it any dates!

Comment: @Scorpion Would you mind pointing me out in the right direction about overriding the operators outside the class? Haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @Scorpion It doesn't seem reasonable to me but well... At least make your function return a `DateTime` so that this behavior is to be expected from its signature.

Comment: @pikausp You can't do that.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski So I'll have to stick with explicitly calling a function?

Comment: It depends. For simple comparisons yes, you'll have to. but if for instance you're trying to sort a list, you can implement your logic in an `IComparator<DateTime?>` and then use `yourList.OrderBy(i => i, yourComparatorInstance)`. One *solution* would be to make your own `Nullable<T>` structure, but I'd advise against that. Another approach would be to make an extension method, ie `dateA.IsLessThan(dateB)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out what you want to happen in every case that your function gets called, then write the code to do that thing. I'm a bit concerned that you're looking for "workarounds" to "writing if statements", as if somehow `if` statements are evil and you shouldn't use them?  Don't try to be clever or sneaky -- you are presumably writing an application that needs to work *and* be maintainable, not entering a code-golf contest.

You should, instead, follow the excellent advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806#926806): spec out how your function needs to work, then implement exactly the specification.  Be clear and accurate.

Your function has four possible combinations of inputs, and you need to figure out what the return value is for each of those inputs. From your edits, it seems like you want the function to return a non-null value as often as possible, so that makes things easy:

1. `function(a, b)`: return whichever of `a`, `b` is smaller.
2. `function(a, null)`: must return `a`
3. `function(null, b)`: must return `b`
4. `function(null, null)`: must return `null`

So, we write that:

```
DateTime? function( DateTime? a, DateTime? b )
{
    // Case 1.
    if (a.HasValue && b.HasValue)
    {
        return a < b ? a : b;
    }

    // Case 2
    if (a.HasValue)
    {
      return a;
    }

    // Case 3 & 4
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```
DateTime? function( DateTime? a, DateTime? b ){
    return a < b ? a : (b ?? a);
}
```

?? is the null-coalescing operator. checkout the msdn: [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms173224.aspx).

Edit: removed redundant code

Comment: This won't work in the case of two `null` parameters.

Comment: If both parameters are null it will return null. In the question it isn't specified what should be returned if both are null.

Comment: @Scorpion it actually works in all cases though it's very slightly redundant: the "true" branch of the ternary can't happen if `a` is `null` so `(a ?? b)` will always return `a`